# Laravel 5.4 - ip_address and user_agent are NULL in sessions database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

Since the update to Laravel 5.4.* (from 5.3.*), the `ip_address` and `user_agent` in my `sessions` database table are `NULL` everywhere.

The `id` and `payload` colums seem to be normal.

I use the standard laravel table layout for the sessions table with mariadb and did not change anything there:

```
id             varchar(255)  
user_id        int(11) NULL  
ip_address     varchar(45) NULL  
user_agent     text NULL     
payload        text  
last_activity  int(11)
```

I don't know where to search for the reason / don't know which part of laravel writes these values to the database. Can someone help, or knows why this could happen?

Comment: could you `dd` the `Request` instance in one of your controller for testing? it should be [populated through the `Request` instance](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php#L236).

Comment: the question is a bit old, but I believe there was a bug + bugfix that fixed this